# Issue with PrimeNG DataTable binding from Http Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs5, primeng-datatable

I am triyng to build a dynamic DataTable using PrimeNG 2.0.5 with Angular 4 but I've got an error : "GET http://localhost:3000/application-detail.component.html 404 (Not Found)" and also "Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load application-detail.component.html ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load application-detail.component.html undefined" ....thanks in advance

Here's my code:

app.detail.component.html ===>

```
<p-dataTable [value]="users" routerLink="my-dashboard">
<p-column *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async" [field]="users.status" [header]="user.data.apps.details[2].state"></p-column>
<p-column *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async" header="Type">{{user.status}}</p-column>
<p-column *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async" header="Etat">{{user.data.apps.details[2].state}}</p-column>
<p-column *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async" header="Depuis">{{user.data.apps.details[2].since}}</p-column> 
</p-dataTable>
```

Here's my Observable: users: Observable

app.detail.component.ts ===>

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataTableModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng'; 
import { UserService } from './user.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: 'application-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['application-detail.component.css'],

})
  export class AppDetailComponent { 

      constructor(public userService: UserService) { }
  }
```

Comment: This is not related to PrimeNG or Observables.

Comment: Ahright but that's first time I use PrimeNG and I am trying to buld that : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Comment: Try adding `./` in the paths

Comment: @Chrillewoodz thanks but it doesn't work..

Comment: Well the issue is that it doesn't find the template, make sure it's the correct path.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz thanks I 'll search in that way

Comment: Even when I put the html and the css to inline template..it doesn't work...strange..

Comment: So I change and everyting to make it simple..in my template I just put it:    <p-dataTable>
<p-column></p-column>
<p-column></p-column>
<p-column></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>      then I've got this error: Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'p-column' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-column' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-column' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: Then when I go in my node modules primeNG is there : myangularproject/node_modules/primeng/components/datatable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144911/discussion-between-emile-cantero-and-chrillewoodz).